# Deletar input selecionado de um array com condição jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Estou com dificuldades para remover inputs selecionados de vários inputs.

### Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btnremoveimg = $('.remover-img');
  btnremoveimg.click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.img img {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
.img button {
  width: 126px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list-inputs">
  <input type='hidden' name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg'>
  <input type='hidden' name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-4.jpg'>
    <input type='hidden' name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg'>
</div>

<div class='img'>

  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</button></div>

</div>

<div class='img'>

  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-4.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</div>

</div>

<div class='img'>

  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-5.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</div>

</div>
```

Eu preciso que ao clicar em `.Remover Imagem` eu delete o input com o mesmo valor do src da imagem. Porem estou tendo dificuldades quando a isso.

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: Deixar o input junto da div que está a img não resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Eu não testei, mas veja se funciona dessa maneira, só que você tem que manter o nome do arquivo diferente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btnremoveimg = $('.remover-img');
  btnremoveimg.click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var valor = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src');
     $('#list-inputs input').each(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == valor) {
           $(this).remove();    
       }

     });
  });

});
```

Eu sugiro fazer pela ID, tipo na HTML você coloca a ID no input:

```
 <div id="list-inputs">
      <input type='hidden' id="img_1" name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg'>
      <input type='hidden' id="img_2" name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-4.jpg'>
      <input type='hidden' id="img_3" name='upload-img[]' value='http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg'>
    </div>

<div id="elm_1" class='img'>

  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</button></div>

</div>

<div id="elm_2" class='img'>

  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-4.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</div>

</div>

<div id="elm_3" class='img'>
  <div class='conteudo-img'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-5.jpg">
  </div>
  <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</div>
</div>
```

E no script, pega pela id:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
          var btnremoveimg = $('.remover-img');
          btnremoveimg.click(function() {
          var pai = $(this).parent();
              pai.remove();
          var inputObj = pai.attr('id').replace('elm_','img_');
              $(inputObj).remove();    
             });
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

você so precisa procurar pelo `input:hidden` com value igual ao `source` da `img` dentro da `div.img` que contem o `button.remover-img` clickado:

```js
var source = document.getElementById("tmpl").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {
  imagens: [
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-1.jpg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-2.jpg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-3.jpg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-4.jpg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-5.jpg",
    "http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-120-120-6.jpg"
  ]
}
document.body.innerHTML = template(context);

var listInputs = document.getElementById("list-inputs");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".remover-img");
buttons = [].slice.apply(buttons);

var onRemoverImgClick = function () {
  var button = this;
  var container = button.parentNode;
  var imagem = button.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  var hidden = listInputs.querySelector("[value='" + imagem.src + "']");

  container.parentNode.removeChild(container);
  listInputs.removeChild(hidden);
}

buttons.forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", onRemoverImgClick)
});
```

```css
.img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.img img {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
}
.img button {
  width: 126px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/template">
  <div id="list-inputs">
    {{#each imagens}}
    <input type='hidden' name='upload-img[]' value='{{this}}' />
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  {{#each imagens}}
  <div class='img'>
    <div class='conteudo-img'>
      <img src="{{this}}" />
    </div>
    <button type='button' class='remover-img'>Remover Imagem</button>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```